# lodash search text in object array

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

In my angular app I have search input

```
 <input
    id="search"
    type="text"
    placeholder="search"
    class="form-control"
    formControlName="search"
    (keydown)="mySearch()"
  >
```

function is:

```
mySearch() {
  // search code here
}
```

This is array where I need to search

```
[
{
    "_id": "1",
    "productName": "test name 1",
    "article": "11111",
},
{
    "_id": "2",
    "productName": "test name 2",
    "article": "11111",
},
{
    "_id": "3",
    "productName": "test name 3",
    "article": "4",
},
{
    "_id": "4",
    "productName": "test name 4",
    "article": "11111",
},
{
    "_id": "5",
    "productName": "test name 5",
    "article": "111111",
},
{
    "_id": "6",
    "productName": "test name 6",
    "article": "11111111",
},
{
    "_id": "7",
    "productName": "test name 7",
    "article": "4d",
}
]
```

when I type "4" as result I need to have all object where string include "4" in productName and article.. like this:

```
[
{
    "_id": "3",
    "productName": "test name 3",
    "article": "4",
},
{
    "_id": "4",
    "productName": "test name 4",
    "article": "11111",
},

{
    "_id": "7",
    "productName": "test name 7",
    "article": "4d",
}
]
```

How I can do that using lodash? I need something like search IN and search in 2 fields in object. Thanks ;)

Comment: I guess that you don't need lodash for that, try to use a filter, like:

articleArray.filter(obj => obj.productName.includes("4") || obj.article.includes("4"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this code:

```
array.filter(a=> _.values(a).some(b => b.includes("4")));
```

_.values is a lodash method

Comment: hey, Alix. thank you very much, but I I get error 
core.js:4352 ERROR TypeError: b.includes is not a function

Comment: because I supposed to type of all value store in object were string.
if you use other types you have to use own methods to Comparison

Comment: Thank you very mush again! I will create array with only string types and then use your code. Thank You!!!!!